# ODE45 time dependent variable with system of diff equations

Tags: matlab

I have a time dependent variable I need to interpolate, and send to my ODE. My EOMs are stored in an function .m file, and I need to send the interpolated values to it, so each value can be used in integration. How do I do this?

The variable I need to interpolate is k. Where k follows this formula

```
k = (h^2*(a+b)-b*h*(a+2*b)*cos(a.*time./b)+b^3)./...
((a+b)*(-2*b*h*cos(a.*time./b)+b^2+h^2).^2);

function [ sv ] = precessing_orbit_sim( t,R ) 
%%% skipped sv 1 and 2
mu = earth.mukm; 
rmag = norm([R(1),R(2)]); 
vmag = norm([R(3),R(4)]);
sv(3)=-R(4)/vmag^2*(vmag^3*k-mu/rmag^3*(-R(4)*R(1)+R(3)*R(2)));
sv(4) =  R(3)/vmag^2*(vmag^3*k-mu/rmag^3*(-R(4)*R(1)+R(3)*R(2)));
end
```

%%% In integrator file

```
[t,out] = ode45(@precessing_orbit_sim,tspan,IC,options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `k` in your ODE function? Something like:

```
function [ sv ] = precessing_orbit_sim( t,R ) 

  %%% skipped sv 1 and 2
  mu = earth.mukm; 
  rmag = norm([R(1),R(2)]); 
  vmag = norm([R(3),R(4)]);

  % Add definition of a, b and h variables
  k = (h^2*(a+b)-b*h*(a+2*b)*cos(a.*t./b)+b^3)./...
      ((a+b)*(-2*b*h*cos(a.*t./b)+b^2+h^2).^2);

  sv(3)=-R(4)/vmag^2*(vmag^3*k-mu/rmag^3*(-R(4)*R(1)+R(3)*R(2)));
  sv(4) =  R(3)/vmag^2*(vmag^3*k-mu/rmag^3*(-R(4)*R(1)+R(3)*R(2)));

end
```

and then call the ODE solver as you normally would:

```
[t,out] = ode45(@precessing_orbit_sim,tspan,IC,options);
```